# APOC installation not working in Neo4J docker container

Tags: docker, neo4j, neo4j-apoc

I have a docker container running with a Graph created. I am following [this](https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.4/installation/#apoc-core) guide to installing APOC. I have copied the JAR file from `/var/lib/neo4j/labs` to `/var/lib/neo4j/plugins` and have restarted the container.

A screenshot of the instructions:

[image: screenshot]

I also enabled `dbms.security.procedures.unrestricted=apoc.*` but the APOC calls do not work after restarting the container.

It always says,

> "There is no procedure with the name `apoc.help` registered for this database instance. Please ensure you've spelled the procedure name correctly and that the procedure is properly deployed."

Is there anything I am missing?

**My Neo4J version**: 4.4.11
**APOC versions I have tried are**: apoc-4.4.0.8-core, apoc-4.4.0.6-core and apoc-4.4.0.9-core

**Update 1**
Script that produces the above output:

```
MATCH (n:FEATURE{name:'Update_Profile'})

CALL apoc.path.spanningTree(n,{maxLevel:15}) YIELD path

RETURN path
```

Second one:

```
CALL apoc.export.cypher.all("all-plain.cypher", {
format: "plain",
useOptimizations: {type: "UNWIND_BATCH", unwindBatchSize: 20}
})
YIELD file, batches, source, format, nodes, relationships, properties, time, rows, batchSize
RETURN file, batches, source, format, nodes, relationships, properties, time, rows, batchSize;
```

**Update 2**

I run the following command inside the docker container to copy the jar file having the current location at `/var/lib/neo4j`

```
cp labs/apoc-4.4.0.8-core.jar /var/lib/neo4j/plugins/
```

After this, I restarted the container using:

```
sudo docker container restart cybersage-neo4j
```

Comment: Please put the actual code that you run based on that guide. Thanks

Comment: @jose_bacoy i just added the code to the question.

Comment: THanks. What I mean is how did you install the APOC based on that guide you followed: https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.0/installation/

Comment: @jose_bacoy sorry if I got you wrong. I already did that. I have added a screenshot of the instructions I followed. and have updated the link to the correct version of the docs

Comment: In your screenshots, you did not post the "ACTUAL" command to copy the jar file into plugins directory. It is only a guide not the code you executed.  We don't want description on how you did it. We want the commands you run.

Comment: @jose_bacoy okay. I just posted the command

Comment: After copying the jar, are you again running `docker run`? Because if that's the case then a new container will be created, and it won't have the jar in the right directory.

Comment: @CharchitKapoor no. I just restart the docker container after copying file. I just added the command into the question

Comment: Try running this command to check if the file was copied or not.
`docker exec -it cybersage-neo4j sh -c "test -f /var/lib/neo4j/plugins/apoc-4.4.0.8-core.jar && echo 'It Exists'"`

Comment: @CharchitKapoor it prints "It Exists"

Comment: Well, that is strange. One last thing can you share the docker run command you used to start the container, for the first time?

Comment: @CharchitKapoor I can't share the command at the moment. The container was created around a week ago and was created by a team member.

Comment: Cool, no issues. My guess is some environment variable is either missing or might have a typo in it. Because the copy worked fine, it should have picked it up.

Comment: @CharchitKapoor It does not need to set any environment variable, I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use **NEO4JLABS_PLUGINS** environment variable to simply install APOC automatically like in the documentation?

```
docker run \
    -p 7474:7474 -p 7687:7687 \
    -v $PWD/data:/data -v $PWD/plugins:/plugins \
    --name neo4j-apoc \
    -e NEO4J_apoc_export_file_enabled=true \
    -e NEO4J_apoc_import_file_enabled=true \
    -e NEO4J_apoc_import_file_use__neo4j__config=true \
    -e NEO4JLABS_PLUGINS=\[\"apoc\"\] \
    -e NEO4J_dbms_security_procedures_unrestricted=apoc.\\\* \
    neo4j:4.0
```